# Get the list of Pods stuck in terminating state for more than 10 mins and remove them in Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, prometheus

I want to get the list of pods stuck in terminating state for more than 10 minutes using Ansible. Currently I am writing a script to do that but I feel there has to be a better way of doing the same. I plan to replace the `describe` pod command with `delete` one in the following code snippet.

```yaml
# Command used to delete :  kubectl delete pod $PodName -n {{item}} --force --grace-period=0;
- name: get list of pods and remove the not ready ones
  shell: |
    noOfPODs=`kubectl get pods -n {{item}} | egrep "0/1|Terminating" | wc -l`;
    if [ $noOfPODs -gt 0 ];
      then
        kubectl get pods -n {{item}} | egrep "0/1|Terminating"   > {{ not_ready_pods_file }} ;
        while read line; do
          PodName=$(echo $line | awk {'print $1'})
          PodTime=$(kubectl describe pod $PodName -n {{item}} | grep Terminating | awk {'print $4'} | tr -d 'mhd)')
          if [ -z $PodTime ];
          then
            PodTime=$(echo $line | awk {'print $5'} | tr -d 'mhd')
          fi
          echo "$PodTime is PodTime"
          if [[ $PodTime == *s ]] ;
          then
            echo "PodTime in seconds"
          else
            if [ $PodTime -gt 10 ];
            then
              echo "\n$PodName" >> {{ deleted_pods_file }};
              kubectl delete pod $PodName -n {{item}} --force --grace-period=0;
            fi
          fi
        done < {{ not_ready_pods_file }}
    else
      echo 'No Pods in NOT READY or Terminating state';
    fi
  environment:
    KUBECONFIG: "./_kubeconfig/{{ env }}/kubeconfig"
  loop:
    - somenamespace
```

- I tried using `k8s_info` in ansible but it gives a huge output which does not have `time`

```yaml
- name: Search for all running pods
  k8s_info:
    kind: Pod
    field_selectors:
      - status.phase=Running
    kubeconfig: "./_kubeconfig/{{ env }}/kubeconfig"
```

Is there any better way of doing this ? like to do in Prometheus etc. Shell script will work but does not seem like the right way.

Answer (score 3):

You could leverage `go-template` for this and do something similar to:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{if eq (.status.phase) ("Terminating")}}{{if gt (.status.startTime) ("2020-07-03T04:18:02Z")}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

`{{if gt (.status.startTime) ("2020-07-03T04:18:02Z")}}` should be replaced by your own time conditions.

Comment: thanks a lot @Adam Otto , for this amazing piece of code :). I will try this as well.  One question though, isn't it doing the same thing as the above shell script. I mean we are shortening our code here but the approach is same. Thoughts ? let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Hey, yes it should do the same thing as the bash script you implemented, of course it may require some tweaking around the startTime and date calculation, also I am not 100% sure that time should be taken from status, maybe you should use the value from `conditions.lastTransitionTime`, but it is really up to your requirements.